# Fingering for piano run

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

I'm looking for some help with a run I'm trying in C. The chord progression is d7, ddim, Cmaj7, and the run is:

```
(G,G#,A,C,E,G),(E,F,A,C,E,G) then it goes down.
```

The run is based of the run from [this Tea For Two jazz solo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7QwnXHrB8s&t=1m35s) 1:35-1:37.

I can do it pretty easily in F, where it's recorded, because the fingering comes naturally. However, I want to do it in C, and I struggle after the first part to reposition my fingers for the second group of notes. For now, I break the rhythm a bit after the E,F of the second group then hasten the A,C,E,G a bit to get back in rhythm. The fingering I use now:

```
(1,2,1,2,3,5), (1,2), (1,2,3,5).
```

I learned to play by ear so my technique is not the best and sometimes I struggle with runs like this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fingering you're using looks fine to me, although coming down you may want to adjust the first figure and personally I would use (1,3,1) instead for the begining to keep it closer to the chromatic scale fingering.

Coming down 1,2,1,2,3,5 may not work well. In my head it seems like it would be easier fingering it a different way and it's not unheard of to adjust fingering ascending and descending. I don't know off the top of my head what would work better.

Answer (score 0):

Your fingering follows the phrasing well, but as an alternative, consider making use of the "long" E at the beginning of the second group to reset your hand/fingering.

(1,3,1,2,3,5),(3),(1,2,3,4,5)

For reference, here are screen captures of the passage from the video linked in the OP.<sup>1</sup>

[image: Tea for Two m21] [image: Tea for Two m22]

The OP transposition differs slightly from the original passage. Not knowing for certain if this is by intention or not, this answer is based on the original, but the fingering will work in either case.

For the first figure, the OP fingering is good; personally I prefer Dom's suggesting of 3 rather than 2 for the (transposed) Ab.

```
X: 1
T: Tea for Two
T: Solo
C: Vincent Youmans
A: Doug McKenzie
M: 4/4
L: 1/16
K: Cmaj
!1!G !3!_A!1!=A (3!2!c!3!e!5!g |
```

The first note of the second figure is the important moment. The finger you use is not critical -- I'll use 3, since it's already on the note from the previous segment. Because that note is relatively long, you can use it to reposition your hand and begin the next bit on 1. (If you want to cover the slight break in sound, a brief pedal will take care of it.)

```
X: 1
T: Tea for Two
T: Solo cont.
C: Vincent Youmans
A: Doug McKenzie
M: 4/4
L: 1/16
K: Cmaj
!3!e3(3!1!f!2!a!3!c' (3!4!e'!5!f'"<("!1!">)"a'
```

---

1<sub>Solo by Doug McKenzie</sub>